# SEO Sitelinks on AJAX page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, seo

I am creating a website for a start-up company. The owner of the company has already a company(since 1999) and at the google entry it has 3 sitelinks. His website is staic(no PHP,JS). My site doesn't use PHP, but AJAX.

I have a index.html with the navbar, the resources and the title carousel.

[image: index.html]

My question is: How can I give the sites the same chance to appear as a sitelink?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to make this site point to the other 3 sites and that google considers it a valid sitelink to those 3 sites, am I right? Or you want the 3 sites to appear as valid sitelinks according to google?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I'm guessing you're asking how to have SEO added to your AJAX-based site. Well, since the Google bot doesn't support JS, just have a "noscript" version of your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I would recommend to sign in to the [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/intl/en_en/webmasters/). There you sign in your website and get a lot of information and resources to improve the information structure of your website. Even if you go for all or the most recommendations Google gives you on theses pages they´ll not guarantee you to show **sitelinks** in the search results.

Google (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en):

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.

I would go with the following checklist:

1. most important, have a web standards based, clean and semantically rich HTML markup
2. for your site's internal links, make sure you use anchor text and `alt` text that's informative, compact, and avoids repetition
3. implement [structured data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en), see also [schema.org](http://schema.org/)
4. create a sitemap (xml) for you website and add the site map in the webmaster tools
5. have patience

Comment: Does Google look if a AJAX page was often loaded? Or does that work ony with <a>

Comment: Disable the JavaScript in your browser and go to your website. Now you can see how the most search engines (crawler or robots) see you page and which information they get. You can´t influence directly how often a search engine crawls your website.